# How can I test a promise that is mocked with Karma?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, promise, karma-runner

My code is:

```
  $scope.openModal = openModal;


  function openModal(data){
    var info = data || {}
    ModalService.showModal({
        templateUrl: ENVApp+"/myview.html",
        controller: "ModalController",
        inputs: {
          icon : "",
          title: "Additional",
          data : info
        }
      }).then(function (modal) {
        modal.element.modal();
        modal.close.then(function (res) {
          if(res.data != 'cancel'){
            if(!res.data.id){
              create(res)
            }else{
              update(res)
            }
          }
        });
      });
  }
```

What's the proper way to test this with Karma? Here's what I have so far:

in my `beforeEach`:

```
  this.ModalService = {
    showModal: function(obj) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      deferred.resolve({
        element: {
          modal: jasmine.createSpy(),
          close: function() {
            var deferred2 = $q.defer();

            return deferred2.promise;
          }
        }
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
  this.UserService = {
    user: {
      id: 2
    },
    updateCategory: function(data, type) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      deferred.resolve({
        data: {
          rows: 'response'
        }
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
  this.controller = $controller('ProfileAdditionalController', {
    '$scope': this.scope,
    '$rootScope': this.rootScope,
    '$state': this.state,
    "$stateParams": this.stateParams,
    'ModalService': this.ModalService,
    'UserService': this.UserService,
    'ResourceService': this.ResourceService,
    '$upload': this.upload,
    'userData': this.userData
  });
```

For my actual test:

```
  it('should open a modal when requested', function() {
    this.scope.openModal();
    expect(this.ModalService.showModal)
  });
```

But that doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you havve `openModal` return the promise it is using from `showModal`. I recently was testing an GUI widget that does something similar to what your code is doing: method A was calling method B, and B returned a promise that A was using. I just decided to have A return the promise it got from B (+ handlers). It simplified testing a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test your `openModal` function on your controller, basically you want to verify the following (3 tests)

1. `ModalService.showModal` is called with some specific options
2. Once modal is displayed, verify that the `then` function is doing what its suppose to do
3. When modal is closed, verify that the  second `then` function is doing what its suppose to do

Firstly, you'll probably need to set up a spy (mock) on ModelService.showModal:
`spyOn(ModalService, 'showModal).and.returnValue($q.when(mockModal))`

Now in your test, you'll trigger the function and a $scope.$digest call:

```
$scope.openModal(data);
$scope.$digest() // to propagate the `resolve()` result of the promise)
```

This would trigger the first `then` callback, (with mockModal passed as a parameter) which you can then verify its behaviour.

Similarly to verify the 2nd callback, you'll need to mock the resolved `modal` object.